# Azure DevOps Pipelines - npm task very slow - 13 mins for 1200 packages

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-scripts

I have a Npm task that is extremely slow in Azure DevOps:

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install --prefer-offline --no-audit --unsafe-perm=true'
    workingDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/xxx.WebHost/ClientApp
  condition: ne(variables.NPM_CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
```

It's a really simple task. The `--prefer-offline --no-audit --unsafe-prem=true` takes about 2 minutes off.

`added 1236 packages from 1289 contributors in 791.318s`

That's about 13 minutes. It takes a few minutes locally. It's ofcause faster locally, but this is crazy. I have cache implemented to help the following builds. These can't be shared for different branches...

This is hosted in `East US 2`.

I have other account in Europe where is run ALOT faster:

`added 1460 packages from 1339 contributors and audited 1479 packages in 39.661s`

Is `West Europe` really that much faster?

Am i doing something really stupid here or is `npm` slow here? Are there broken

I know there is alternatives to `npm`. I just want to make 100% sure this is not something I'm doing wrong.

Update 1:

Just discovered this might be useful inforation. We are running:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that it varies between runs and agents.

In a current project we are running our build pipelines in azure, Europe west, and the same build can take anything from 5 to 25 minutes depending on the agent running the build.

We do:
Set Node version
Upgrade npm
NPM install (less packages than you are)
build using npm (we are building 5 different packages in a monorepo)
linting

We are using windows-latest at the moment and they can vary a lot. Mostly they are between 7-10 mins for our builds, but sometimes they complete in 5 if we get a fast agent. Sometimes it can run for 20 minutes on another agent on the same build.

Comment: But is this only for the `npm install` part? I guess this is more bandwidth heavy than CPU 
 ... but it's really pissing me off. When cache kicks in, I can do a build in 3-4 mins ... without it takes betwwen 15-20 mins.

Comment: I looked at our 8 last builds.

The npm i command took

* 2m 32s
* 3m 33s
* 4m 37s
* 2m 34s
* 4m 46s
* 3m 15s
* 3m 55s
* 4m 34s

Some major difference in, some taking twice as long as others,.

Comment: So I guess we can just agree that this is basically a magic black box. Since I see both 4 mins on one and 13 mins on other projects. Maybe some on the future figures out what the hell is going on. For now ... but it's pissing me off ... I hate magic :-)